# Why my SharpDevelop didn't have SVN Addin?

Tags: svn, add-in, sharpdevelop

My SharpDevelop Version is 4.0.0.

Some one said I can found at Tools->Subversion, but I didn't found.

Should I go to download it? What url is it?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't downvote the close, this really is a common question for SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at their website?

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Features.aspx

> integrated Subversion support ([TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) )

I'm going to assume you have to have [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) installed (similar to the way [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) works in conjunction with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)  in Visual Studio).

Comment: I have installed TortoiseSVN 1.6.9 after sharpdevelop installed, but in tool menu, there is not the TortoiseSVN item. By the way, Windows shell (right click menu) had the TSVN item.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found it in project right click menu. I always use asknsvn in VS.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the 32-bit TSVN installed, this solved my problem.

Comment: NomisSilloc, I installed the 64bit version of TSVN and it didn't show up in SharpDevelop. 
When I try to install the 32bit version, it says "You are attempting to run the 32-bit installer on a 64-bit version of windows. Please install the 64bit version".

Comment: @mcmillab: The issue with the 32-bit vs. 64-bit registry has been long fixed; SharpDevelop now uses 64-bit TSVN on a 64-bit OS.